# How can I rotate a vector representing some projectiles after casting?

Tags: c#

I have this little code for a Player and a Projectile flying from the Owner(Player) to the mouse cursor . I need to fix the problem for the other projectiles to cast in a "cone like" shape.
For now , I have this

```
//this is used for rotation
public static class Vector2Extensions
{
    public static Vector2 Rotate(this Vector2 v, double degrees)
    {
        return new Vector2(
            (float)(v.X * Math.Cos(degrees) - v.Y * Math.Sin(degrees)),
            (float)(v.X * Math.Sin(degrees) + v.Y * Math.Cos(degrees))
        );
    }
}


//this is when I cast the spell
public void OnFinishCasting(IChampion owner, ISpell spell, IAttackableUnit target)
    {
        var current = new Vector2(owner.X, owner.Y);
        var to = Vector2.Normalize(new Vector2(spell.X, spell.Y) - current);
        var range = to * 1150;
        var trueCoords = current + range;

        spell.AddProjectile("Fireball", owner.X, owner.Y, trueCoords.X, trueCoords.Y);
        spell.AddProjectile("Fireball", owner.X, owner.Y, trueCoords.Rotate(Math.PI , 15).X, trueCoords.Rotate(Math.PI, 15).Y);
        spell.AddProjectile("Fireball", owner.X, owner.Y, trueCoords.Rotate(Math.PI , 45).X, trueCoords.Rotate(Math.PI, 45).Y);
        spell.AddProjectile("Fireball", owner.X, owner.Y, trueCoords.Rotate(Math.PI , 90).X, trueCoords.Rotate(Math.PI, 90).Y);

    }
```

Let me explain the code a little :

> owner.X and owner.Y are the player's position , from where the spell is going to cast.
>
> trueCoords.X and trueCoords.Y are the mouse's position , to where the spell is supposed to cast.

Using this method, the first projectile goes how it's supposed to (to the mouse position) , the rest of them are going very wrong , SOMETIMES (at some unknown positions , are going as expected to ) and at some positions they are going to random positions .
For example , I'm casting my fireball to the very Right of the screen , the other ones are casting , maybe upper side , maybe downside , maybe backside of the player's position.
How can I fix this so I can cast them in this "cone" shape every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rotating not the direction ("to"/"range") but the target position, what you want to do is apply the rotation to the direction (both the "to" vector or the "range" vector should work), then apply the origin position to that direction vector (otherwise you are not just rotating the direction of the fireball, you are basically rotating the mouse position all over the place).
A small polish thing: Maybe you want to use for the angles: -45,-15,15,45 
so the middle of the cone aims at the mouse position, not the side of the cone (depending on your game/spell etc of course

```
    var to = Vector2.Normalize(new Vector2(spell.X, spell.Y) - current);
    var range = to * 1150;

    var trueCoords0 = current + range
    var trueCoords1 =  current + range.Rotate(Math.PI, 15);
    var trueCoords2 =  current + range.Rotate(Math.PI, 45);
    var trueCoords3 =  current + range.Rotate(Math.PI, 90);

    spell.AddProjectile("Fireball", owner.X, owner.Y, trueCoords.X, trueCoords.Y);
    spell.AddProjectile("Fireball", owner.X, owner.Y, trueCoords1.X, trueCoords1.Y);
    spell.AddProjectile("Fireball", owner.X, owner.Y, trueCoords2.X, trueCoords2.Y);
    spell.AddProjectile("Fireball", owner.X, owner.Y, trueCoords3.X, trueCoords3.Y);
```